# Pushing element into array inside for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically generate a 50 element array from a single element, by just modifying one value on each loop.

```
const eventRecords = { Records: [] }
      for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        const aRecord = Object.assign({}, eventS3Chunk.Records[0])
        aRecord.s3.object.key = `F7kdfh2Dj3j2s8/uploads/10000_users_without_password-20190102T030405Z/${i}.csv`
        eventRecords.Records.push(Object.assign({}, aRecord))
      }
```

eventRecords.Records end up with 50 copies of same element with `s3.object.key = F7kdfh2Dj3j2s8/uploads/10000_users_without_password-20190102T030405Z/49.csv`.

Comment: Object.assign is not a deep copy, for copying nested object one method is JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

Comment: Take a look into deep cloning. In your example, the s3 and/or object is being passed by reference and therefore assigning the key to one, affects all records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's because you're creating a shallow copy of `Records[0]`, use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eventS3Chunk.Records[0]));`
 :

```js
const eventS3Chunk = {
  Records: [{
    s3: {
      object: {
        key: "a"
      }
    }
  }]
};

const eventRecords = Array.from({
  length: 50
}, (_, i) => {
  const aRecord = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eventS3Chunk.Records[0]));
  aRecord.s3.object.key = `F7kdfh2Dj3j2s8/uploads/10000_users_without_password-20190102T030405Z/${i}.csv`;
  return aRecord;
});

console.log(eventRecords)
```